# Unable to create Genymotion virtual device from Android studio on windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I installed Genymotion on my windows 10 and unable to create a virtual device on Android studio. I got an error " Unable to start the virtual device. VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device. To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptPTl.png) Please need your help.

Answer (score 0):

What I did on my Windows 10 laptop is install VirtualBox separately (it was previously installed by Genymotion, but I hadn't used it in a year and I guess something happened)

1. Download it from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and install it.
2. Go back to Genymotion and try to launch the emulator again. Now it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows 10,
and found that my virtual box is not completely installed or has been removed somehow

`try to reinstall virtual box`: [download](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

tip: be careful that your genymotion's version to be matched with the virtual box which you're going to install.